# How to read iSight camera current focus distance (focal length)?

Tags: macos, api, isight

Let's say you're holding your hand two feet away from a Mac's iSight camera and it's the thing in focus. I would like to be able to read this distance (either directly or by getting some other focus data that allows me to calculate the distance) from the iSight through some API. Anybody know if this is possible? I looked through the QTKit documentation and couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the iSight camera is a fixed focus camera which means there is no focal length to detect.